# How to display video preview in tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pygame, moviepy

I am having problem that how to display a video preview  window inside the tkinter window. Below code will play video but i want to show that video in the tkinter window..

Python Code:

```py
from moviepy.editor import *
from moviepy.video.fx.resize import resize  
import pygame   

pygame.display.set_caption('Kumawat!')   
clip=VideoFileClip('mk.mp4')    
w=1300    
h=700    
display=(w,h)       
clip.resize(display).preview()    
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: The normal way is to generate a filmstrip of your video file. Unless by preview you mean to play the whole file just in smaller size.

Comment: if you have to use `moviepy` then you can use `for image in clip.iter_frames()` to display frame by frame like in @BrunoVermeulen answer. As I know `Moviepy` also uses `imageio`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some researching it does not seem you can embed the clip easily into a tkinter frame. The solution I came up with is:

- use `imageio` to download the video
- extract each video frame using an iterator into an image
- convert the image to a ImageTk
- add this image to a tkinter label

In below example I have added two control buttons to start and stop the video as well as an waiting loop to run the video at real time assuming 24 frames per second. I have not investigated how to include sound.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
import imageio
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

global pause_video

# download video at: http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4
video_name = "toystory.mp4"
video = imageio.get_reader(video_name)


def video_frame_generator():
    def current_time():
        return time.time()

    start_time = current_time()
    _time = 0
    for frame, image in enumerate(video.iter_data()):

        # turn video array into an image and reduce the size
        image = Image.fromarray(image)
        image.thumbnail((750, 750), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        # make image in a tk Image and put in the label
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

        # introduce a wait loop so movie is real time -- asuming frame rate is 24 fps
        # if there is no wait check if time needs to be reset in the event the video was paused
        _time += 1 / 24
        run_time = current_time() - start_time
        while run_time < _time:
            run_time = current_time() - start_time
        else:
            if run_time - _time > 0.1:
                start_time = current_time()
                _time = 0

        yield frame, image


def _stop():
    global pause_video
    pause_video = True


def _start():
    global pause_video
    pause_video = False


if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Video in tkinter')

    my_label = tk.Label(root)
    my_label.pack()
    tk.Button(root, text='start', command=_start).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    tk.Button(root, text='stop', command=_stop).pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    pause_video = False
    movie_frame = video_frame_generator()

    while True:
        if not pause_video:
            frame_number, frame = next(movie_frame)
            my_label.config(image=frame)

        root.update()

    root.mainloop()
```